# In a Spring example, how is a Validator object generated?

Tags: spring, validation

I am studying a spring exmaple. And I found the following code. I can't understand the construct function. A validator interface is passed to this function. How is this validator generated? Thanks in advance.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/account")
public class AccountController {

    private Map<Long, Account> accounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Account>();

    private Validator validator;

@Autowired
public AccountController(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> create(@RequestBody Account account, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> failures = validator.validate(account);
    if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return validationMessages(failures);
    } else {
        accounts.put(account.assignId(), account);
        return Collections.singletonMap("id", account.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You use Autowired on constructor Spring looks for Validator implementation/

In this example Spring injects its default Validator implementation:
org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Here's more:
section: 5.7.2.1 Injecting a Validator

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html

Answer (score 1):

The validator can be any class that implements Springs [Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) interface and is available in the current application context. By default Spring autowires by type. This means that every bean which implements the `Validator` interface can satisfy the constructor of `AccountController`. I don't know the exact example but there might be something like an `AccountValidator` bean available int the application context.

Be aware that this approach could cause problem if multiple validator beans are available in the application context.

See the [Validation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) in the spring documentation for details on the `Validator` interface.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find any implementation of Validator in this project. Will Spring provides a default implementation of Validator in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some concrete implementation of Validator.Without that it is not possible.
Further to support my answer see that it is being @Autowired.
Please post the link from which you are studying or check the source code for the presence of validaor class.

Also,check this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) There is no concrete implementation by default.